# AngularJS - Display properties with '$' as first character

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display a list of object properties and their values using AngularJS. Some of the property names begin with a '$' character. Those property names do not show up. I would very much like to avoid editing the source data just so Angular is happy. Here's a small example exhibiting the problem:

```
  <p data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in {'$no': 'rock', 'yes': 'hard place'}">
      {{ key }}: {{ value }}
  </p>
```

The above code only displays the 2nd item.

Oddly, you can force Angular to display these properties if you know the property name:

```
{{ my_object.$no }}
```

I'm a bit new to Angular, is there a filter or something else I'm missing in order to display these properties?

Note: I'm using the latest AngularJS version 1.2.14.

### Update

I submitted an issue on Github to the angular development team:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6520

There's not really any new information there and it was closed as "Works as expected" :(

So, the answer from @Gruff Bunny below is likely the best answer at this time.

Comment: i know angular likes to use `$` to refer to internal/protected stuff

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah, I was thinking there may be a link there, but it seems strange the Angular devs would let this interfere in valid user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses $ as a prefix for it's own properties, so the ngRepeat directive ignores properties of an object that begin with a $.

Here's the code that iterates over an object in angular:

```
collectionKeys = [];
for (key in collection) {
    if (collection.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.charAt(0) != '$') {
        collectionKeys.push(key);
    }
}
```

One workaround would be to convert the object to an array and use that in the UI:

```
angular.forEach( $scope.obj, function(value, key){
    $scope.arr.push( { key: key, value: value } );
});

<p data-ng-repeat="obj in arr">{{ obj.key }}: {{ obj.value }}</p>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/87CGw/5/)</kbd>

Comment: +1 Thanks for tracking down where this is happening. I'd also thought of just explicitly creating a dictionary, but thought I was missing something in Angular. This seems like a bug to me, as I found no mention of this behaviour in the docs (I could have missed it though). I'll post an issue on their Github repo.

Comment: @Gruff i didn't copied your answer,
i didn't read your comment,i just checked source code and posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Key value prefixed with "$" sign is ignored in ng-repeat directive:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection(rhs, function ngRepeatAction(collection){   
    ........

           collectionKeys = [];
           for (key in collection) {
              if (collection.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.charAt(0) != '$') {
                collectionKeys.push(key);
              }
            }
    ........
```

});

Angular.js LineNumber : 19598